# Pegar valor de <span> com PHP

Tags: php

Onde está "VALOR" é o resultado que preciso pegar e mostrar

```
<span class="nomeClass" title="titulo" tabindex="0" aria-label="number">VALOR </span>
```

```
$el = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
```

Parei nessa parte e não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Olá @Paulo Previatto,

Você quer obter o valor de um input, isso?

Comment: desculpe, o site nao mostro o código inteiro, atualizei aki o  post , de uma olhada novamente

Comment: atualizei, então é o valor de um elemento html, no caso uma span. Vc tem conhecimento em jquery?

Comment: pouco conheçimento amigo

Comment: vc já obteve o valor vindo do banco de dados com php e agora gostaria de ler com js/jquery para poder manipulá-lo em demais situações de sua aplicação, isso?

Comment: estou puxando uma pagina de fora, pra eu nao puxar toda a pagina e ficar carregado de conteudo, queria pegar apenas esse VALOR  que esta na pagina dentro dessa span

Comment: Paulo com ou sem jquery se span não tiver um IDm você precisa de encontrar outra forma de encontrar o elemento na página, é necessário o endereço da página ou então o código HTML para poder criar um query

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Neo, consegui resolver o problema !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A sua pergunta é bem ampla pois nada sabemos a respeito do código fonte da página que deveremos extrair o texto de determinada tag `span` cuja classe é `nomeClass`.
>
> Podem existir inúmeras tags `span` com a classe `nomeClass` e até mesmo, - porque não -  outros elementos com a mesma classe `nomeClass`, veja por exemplo o código HTML a seguir:

**exemplo.html**

```
<!--Suposto Código fonte da pagina -->

<html>

<head>
<title>Página</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="nomeClass">div 1</div>

    <span class="nomeClass"> Previous</span>

    <br>
    
    <input type="text" class="nomeClass">
    
    <br>

    <span class="nomeClass">Complete HTML </span>

    <br>

    <span class="nomeClass">Next </span>
    
    <div class="nomeClass">div 2</div>

    <span class="nomeClass"> Previous</span>

    <br>
    <span class="nomeClass">Complete HTML </span>

    <p>
    <span class="nomeClass" title="titulo" tabindex="0" aria-label="number">VALOR</span> 
    </p>
    <p>
    <span class="nomeClass" title="titulo" tabindex="0" aria-label="number">Esse VALOR Não interessa</span> 
    </p>
    <p>
    <span class="nomeClass" title="titulo" tabindex="0" aria-label="number">Outro VALOR Não interessa</span> 
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

> Note que o texto do elemento que queremos obter é o elemento de índice `8`, ou seja o nono elemento cuja classe é `nomeClass`, independentemente de ser uma tag `span`.

Supondo o HTML acima podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

**loadexemplo.php**

```
    <?php
    $html = file_get_contents("exemplo.html");
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    @$DOM->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($DOM);

    $classname = 'nomeClass';

    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $result=$result.$node->nodeValue.",";
    }

    $partes = explode(',',$result);
    $textoSpan=$partes[8];
    
    echo $textoSpan;

    ?>
```

[**exemplo acima rodando no servidor**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/loadexemplo.php)

> De qualquer forma, mesmo que haja apenas um elemento com class `nomeClass` o código acima funcionará perfeitamente. Não se esqueça que neste caso o índice do elemento deverá ser `0` (zero)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo, consegui resolver o problema!

Answer (score 1):

Paulo você pode colocar um id no span para pegar o valor do mesmo.

```
<!--No HTML-->
<span id="mySpan">Conteúdo do meu span</span>
//No javascript
document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML;
```

Para pegar com elemento class.

```
var elementoUm = document.getElementsByClassName('mySpan')[0].innerHTML;
```

Nesse caso o document.getElementsByClassName vai pegar todos os elementos com a classe mySpan e no [0] estou pegando o primeiro elemento da página com a class mySpan.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: estou puxando conteudo de outra pagina, e no código nao tem ID a span

Comment: em vez de puxar a id da span, nao poderia puxar tipo atraves da class ou title ??

Comment: Acrescentei o exemplo com class na resposta, pois como comentário é difiícil de visualizar.

Comment: sim com esse script consigo pegar a linha, e pra mostrar  como faço ?

Comment: Nesse caso é só você jogar a variável elementoUm onde deseja. Por exemplo se quiser que o conteúdo vá para a div teste seria. document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = elementoUm;

Comment: Muito Obrigado Roberto, consegui resolver o problema !

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu problema é de PHP, resolva-o com PHP - não entendi porque outras respostas utilizaram JavaScript.

Você iniciou bem. De fato, a solução será utilizando a classe `DOMDocument`, porém, para fazer a busca do elemento na árvore, será melhor você utilizar a classe [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php)

```
$html = <<<HTML
    <span class="nomeClass" title="titulo" tabindex="0" aria-label="number">VALOR</span>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//span[@class="nomeClass"]') as $span) {
    echo $span->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SteelAuthenticAbandonware)</sup>

Perceba que foi instanciado o objeto `DOMXPath` em relação ao `DOMDocument` e executado a busca `//span[@class="nomeClass"]`, que buscará todos os elementos `span` que possuem a classe igual a `nomeClass`. Como o retorno pode ser um *array*, é necessário iterar sobre o resultado com o `foreach`, obtendo o valor do elemento com `nodeValue`.

Para o exemplo acima, a saída será `VALOR`.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo, consegui resolver o problema!

Answer (score 0):

creio q com jquery vc consegue pegar o q precisa.
`var valor = $('.nomeClass').text();`
`alert(valor);// VALOR`

lember-se q geralmente se usa a mesma classe para vários elementos na mesma página html. prefira usar o `Id`, por exemplo.

Comment: Deixei meu voto negativo por dois motivos: 1) a pergunta é sobre PHP, não JavaScript; 2) porque mesmo se fosse JavaScript, usar jQuery para apenas isso seria completamente desnecessário.

Comment: nem sempre o q se quer e como se quer fazer não são as melhores opções. os comentários podem ajudam ou não.

Comment: eu teria vergonha de fazer uma pergunta dessas com um curriculo igual ao seu. boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado, problema ja foi resolvido !